# Alamofire doesn't catch error

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, afnetworking, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to get data from my server. However, it doesn't catch the error, as the error returned is `nil`. I've tested with AFNetworking, and it works fine. For both operation, the status code returned is `401 Unauthorized` . Is there's something with my code?

I'm using [GrapeAPI](https://github.com/intridea/grape) for my backend. All it does is just to return the error on fail request

**GrapeAPI**

```
error!('Unauthorized', 401)
```

**AFNetworking**

```
manager.GET("someUrl", parameters: nil, success: { (_, object) in

        }, failure: { (operation, error) in
            // These are the outputs. I'm not assigning any values
            // error.localizedDescription = "Request failed: unauthorized (401)"
            // statusCode = 401
        })
```

**Alamofire**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: nil)
        .response { (a,b,data,error) in
        // These are the outputs. I'm not assigning any values
        // error = nil
        // data = {"error":"Unauthorized"}
        // statusCode = 401
        }
```

I can check the failure using the statusCode. But I prefer to check the error object instead. However, since the error is `nil` in Alamofire, it's quite confusing to check whether the request has failed or not.

Comment: You need to explicitly call `.validate()` before your call to `.response()`

Comment: @mattt That works. Is there any reason why Alamofire is designed to behave this way by default and AFNetworking is not?

Comment: Yes, explicit opt-in is better in this circumstance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Matt has mentioned in the comment, I need to add `.validate()` before calling `.response()`. This is by design. Final code as below:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: nil)
    .validate()
    .response { (a,b,data,error) in
    // error won't be nil now
    // and statusCode will be 401
    }
```

Read [this detailed explanation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/536#issuecomment-113945537)(thanks!) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`Alamofire` does not see `401 Unauthorized` as an error as it is an valid return. In your comment code you are assigning a value to error not checking it for error, it should be:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "url", parameters: nil)
        .response { (a,b,data,error) in
        if error != nil{
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let data = data{
               //You should probably use a switch statement here
               if data.statusCode == 401 {
                   println("Unauthorized")
               } else if data.statusCode == 200 {
                   println("Success")
               }
           }
        }
```

I am not sure if i understand correctly your problem, but I hope that help!

Comment: Updated my code. Those are the output values. I'm not assigning any values to any variables :)